# Randomize order of <a> links on page using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a list of links sitting inside a  tag right now. I would like for the page to 'reorganize' the order of each link on page reload (page view) and display the results.

For example:

```
<div id="testgroup">
     <a href="1.html" id="1">1</a>
     <a href="2.html" id="2">2</a>
     <a href="3.html" id="3">3</a>
     <a href="4.html" id="4">4</a>
     <a href="5.html" id="5">5</a>
</div>
```

On page reload, the soure code would look like:

```
<div id="testgroup">
     <a href="5.html" id="5">5</a>
     <a href="1.html" id="1">1</a>
     <a href="3.html" id="3">3</a>
     <a href="4.html" id="4">4</a>
     <a href="2.html" id="2">2</a>
</div>
```

or some other random order

Is there a very basic jQuery DOM manipulation script to accomplish this? If it helps, the page is built on PHP as well.

Comment: How are the links added to the page?  Do they come from a database? do you have them in an array?

Comment: @Johnie Karr - for the time being and this example, they are static and hardcoded into the actual PHP page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If simplicity is more important than randomness:**

You can use `get` to convert the jQuery object to an array, then use the native `sort` with a function designed to randomize it.  Then put the randomly arranged array back into the DOM.

```
var array = $("#testgroup").children().get().sort( function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
$("#testgroup").append(array);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4e7cs/

**If you are looking for true shuffling:**

You can utilize the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle):

```
var array = $("#testgroup").children().toArray();
var i = array.length,
    j, temp;
while (--i) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

$("#testgroup").append(array);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4e7cs/3/

Here is a [writeup](http://sroucheray.org/blog/2009/11/array-sort-should-not-be-used-to-shuffle-an-array/) on why the first is bad, but I'll leave it here for completeness.

Comment: you technically gave the 'correct' answer to my question. I am going to go the PHP route after additional consideration for now but appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function to randomize arrays.  You can do the randomization on the server side.

```
<?php
$links = array(
    1 => '1.html',
    2 => '2.html',
    3 => '3.html',
    4 => '4.html',
    5 => '5.html'
);
$shuffledLinks = shuffle_assoc($links);

foreach ($shuffledLinks as $value=>$key) {
    echo '<a href="'.$key.'" id='.$value.'>'.$value.'</a><br/>';
}
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list;

    $keys = array_keys($list);
    shuffle($keys);
    $random = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key)
        $random[$key] = $list[$key];

    return $random;
} 
?>
```

Ok...this is now fixed and tested.  Actually shuffle() did not work on associative arrays so I borrowed [andjones at gmail dot com's shuffle_assoc() function for that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php).

I also mixed up my concatenation where I was using '+' instead of '.' O.o  Mixing up my JavaScript and PHP syntax.  I apologize about that.

Allen

Comment: the code above would not work properly but I do get the idea. Thanks for your help. Any reason to use PHP over jquery though?

Comment: Normally PHP is faster then javascript. + there is no warranty the end user is using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a plugin that actualy does that : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

But if you are using PHP you could sort it directly on the server?

Comment: Personally, I would sort it using PHP as David mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - while I believe it is certainly feasible to do so, I want to make it as simple as possible for anybody on our team to add a new hyperlink (they have ZERO coding background), matching the formats above it when needed and pass through a jQuery function to do the actual randomizing.

Comment: @David - solid point about the client not using JS; while I read recently over 70% of the time they do, always something to consider. Perhaps I will end up going the PHP route after all.

Comment: @David - it was hard to give credit elsewhere as your answer is technically the route I am going to use but had to give Dennis credit for answering the initial question and his time put in as well.

Comment: @JM4 Our goal is to help you, not only to get the credit, but thanks for the informations.